# If I have 4 custom login buttons and I want to show the button used to last login on top, how can I do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have 4 different login method for my app. Each method has a separate component associated to it. I want to rearrange the buttons based on what was the last used login method.

I already have a way to determine my last login.

```
  let lastSignedInMethod
if (ticketsState?.mjrLoginType === 'apple') {
    lastSignedInMethod = strings.tickets.login.apple
} else if (ticketsState?.mjrLoginType === 'google') {
    lastSignedInMethod = strings.tickets.login.google
} else if (ticketsState?.mjrLoginType === 'phone') {
    lastSignedInMethod = strings.tickets.login.yourPhoneNumber
} else if(ticketsState?.mjrLoginType === 'username'){
    lastSignedInMethod = strings.tickets.login.email
}
```

I have the following 4 components.

```
<UsernameSignIn cta={hasSignedInAlready && lastSignedInMethod === strings.tickets.login.email} />
<PhoneSignIn cta={hasSignedInAlready && lastSignedInMethod === strings.tickets.login.yourPhoneNumber} />
<AppleSignIn
     cta= {hasSignedInAlready && lastSignedInMethod === strings.tickets.login.apple}
     setParentSigningIn={signingIn => setFreeze(signingIn)} />
<GoogleSignIn 
     cta={hasSignedInAlready && lastSignedInMethod === strings.tickets.login.google } 
     setParentSigningIn={signingIn => setFreeze(signingIn)} />
```

I am render the 4 components with some dividers and some other styling but I want to rearrange them based on the value of `lastSignedInMethod`.
You can ignore the `cta` property, I'm using this to color the button but It can be ignored for this functionality.

I am thinking of adding all the components to an array and then have some property on the component to be able to uniquely identify them using `strings.tickets.login.apple` string for the `<AppleSignIn/>` component and same for the others and then just sorting the array based on the value of `lastSignedInMethod`.

Is there a better way of doing this, or am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Create the array of button types and sort that according to usage. To render `map` through the list.

```
const buttons = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3', 'button4'];

...

{buttons.map((button) => 
  { 
    switch (button) {
      case 'button1': { 
        return <Button
          title="Button 1"
          onPress={() => {}}/>
      }
...
      case 'button4': { 
        return <Button
          title="Button 4"
          onPress={() => {}}/>
      }
    }
  }
)}
```